# Lua Corona - how to listen to widget.newScrollView listener during sliding

Tags: lua, widget, coronasdk

I have a background image behind my widget.newScrollView component.
I want to move my background image at half the speed of my newScrollView.
This works ok while I'm dragging my Scroll View but when i release the mouse the Scroll View keeps sliding but my background stops moving. Please show me how to trap the sliding events. 
Many Thanks

Here is some of my code:

```
local function scrollListener( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if ( phase == "began" ) then print( "Scroll view was touched" )
    elseif ( phase == "moved" ) then print( "Scroll view was moved" )
        nebulaeBgnd.x = event.x/2;
    elseif ( phase == "ended" ) then print( "Scroll view was released" )
    end
end

local a1 = display.newImage( "planetHexs/001.png", _topLeft_x, _topLeft_y);

local scrollView = widget.newScrollView(
{
    top = 0,
    left = 0,
    width = display.actualContentWidth,
    height = display.actualContentHeight,
    scrollWidth = 0,
    scrollHeight = 0,
    listener = scrollListener,
    backgroundColor = { 0, 0, 0},
    verticalScrollDisabled=true;
}

scrollView:insert( a1 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a Runtime `enterFrame` listener. We do this in our games sometimes and it works great. For example:

```
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", function() 
    local scrollX, scrollY = scrollView:getContentPosition()
    nebulaeBgnd.x = scrollX * 0.5 -- Tip: multiplication is faster than division
end)
```

This will constantly listen yo your scrollview position regardless of it being touched or not. You might need to compensate for x by adding or subtracting half the screen width, depending on your scrollview position setup. You can read about [getContentPosition here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ScrollViewWidget/getContentPosition.html).

A **really important** note on Runtime event listeners:

> Runtime event listeners, on the other hand, must be removed when you're finished using them. Otherwise, they'll continue to run because the Runtime event is global. Not only will this cause a memory leak, but if any functions executing in the Runtime attempt to reference object(s) that no longer exist, the program will crash. See Removing Event Listeners below for more information.

[Here is the documentation about removing event listeners](https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/events/detectEvents/index.html#removing-event-listeners).

Comment: Thanks Basilio, that's great